# Certificate private key permissions in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, acl, x509certificate2, cng

I'm trying to import a certificate with private key into the Windows Certificate Store. I can successfully import the certificate using the below

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new(certByteArray, certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
X509Store store = new(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
```

But the problem I've got is, how to give a user access to the private key programmatically.
I've found these links helpful:
https://www.pkisolutions.com/accessing-and-using-certificate-private-keys-in-net-framework-net-core/
[CngKey Assign permission to machine key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018834/cngkey-assign-permission-to-machine-key)

[Set Certificate PrivateKey Permissions in .NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543195/set-certificate-privatekey-permissions-in-net-5)

I can grant access via the UI with certlm.msc > Drag certificate to Personal store > Right click certificate > All Tasks > Manage private keys > Add the user and permission
But I need to do this programmatically

There are changes from .NET Full Framework which is where the examples come from. I've spent more than a day on it, tried multiple certificates, certificate is definitely marked as exportable and running VS as administrator. I'm happy with a Windows only solution

This is about as close as I've got

```
const string NCRYPT_SECURITY_DESCR_PROPERTY = "Security Descr";
const CngPropertyOptions DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = (CngPropertyOptions)4;

X509Store trustedPeopleStore = new(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
trustedPeopleStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

var certificates = trustedPeopleStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", false);

RSA rsa = certificates[0].GetRSAPrivateKey();
RSACng rsaCng = rsa as RSACng;

CngProperty prop = rsaCng.Key.GetProperty(NCRYPT_SECURITY_DESCR_PROPERTY, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION);
```

I can see the rsaCng.Key present in debug, but it fails on the next line (it definitely is exportable) getting the property with
`Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Key not valid for use in specified state.'` 
I've also read comments that you shouldn't try setting the acl directly on the file, but not sure if that is correct or not

Comment: My guess would be that the user running you WebApp doesn't have the required permission to access the cert store. Did you try saving all the Private Keys in a folder in your App_Data and then give access to them based on user logins?

Answer (score 0):

See [this code project post](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Forums/View.aspx?fid=1649&msg=2062983) for some example code that grants access programmatically (specifically look at the "AddAccessToCertificate" method).

Check this for more info: [Programmatically adding certificate to personal store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457509/programmatically-adding-certificate-to-personal-store)